# PayPal IPN Listener URL

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I would like to configure my IPN Listener URL but unfortunately, I can't find where to set the URL from. I have tried to search in the documentation of PayPal but all in vain. When I log in to PayPal, I have got only two tabs i.e. My Account and Send Payment.

Where are the IPN settings located? I will be very grateful.

Thanks,

Matrich

Answer (score 2):

It's cause they're moving everything over to x.com, it's kinda annoying.

In the final step of "Create PayPal payment button" you have a TextArea for "Advanced Variables" you can then set the IPN in a querystring variable named: `notify_url`:

```
notify_url=https://www.mywebsite.com/PayPal_IPN
```

Here's more information for [Website Payments Standard](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)